# How to fadeIn my image into the container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show my image into the imageContainer but I can't do it with my code. Here is my code:

```
document.getElementById("imageContainer").innerHTML='<img src="'+data[3].pic+' " class= "imgbig">';
```

I tried something like this but not working.

```
$(document.getElementById("imageContainer").innerHTML='<img src="'+data[3].pic+' " class= "imgbig">').fadeIn("slow");
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I made some edits to your formatting that format the code as `code`. See more here http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.appendTo()` for getting back the object of appended one,

```
$('<img>', {'src': data[3].pic, 'class' : 'imgbig'})
      .appendTo("#imageContainer")
        .hide().fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

Being a bit more verbose and jQuery'ish probably helps

```
var img = $('<img />', {
              src     : data[3].pic,
              'class' : 'imgbig'
          });

img.hide();

$('#imageContainer').html(img);

img.fadeIn('slow');
```